# Macbook Pro mid-2012 restarts after entering password

Tags: macbook-pro, password, restart, firmware, nvram

Macbook Pro mid-2012 restarts after entering password and gives an error after restart

I'm unable to use any other boot command like Command + R etc as it leads to a screen with a lock and I've forgotten firmware password. I've even tried the trick to swap/remove rams and reset nvram 3 times, but nothing works.

How can I start my macbook?

Comment: Do you still have a spinning disk?

Comment: I'm actually not sure.

Comment: My disk isn't continously spinning during startup.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if you have the original hard disk drive or an SSD.  Are you saying that your disk goes to sleep right after startup?  Can you run the command `diskutil info disk0 | grep -i SMART`.  Let me know the result.

Answer (score 1):

Without the firmware password you will need to take your machine to an Apple Store or official Service Provider, along with proof of ownership.

Ref: [Apple KB: How to set a firmware password on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204455)

The old 'remove the RAM' or 'reset NVRAM' tricks etc only work with older PowerPC Macs, not Intel.

Comment: There is not any apple store in the country I live in. On top of that, I don't have to proof of ownership of that macbook as I'm not the first buyer of that. I have bought an old one.

Comment: That's the only method. There's no way round it - otherwise what would be the point of having it as a security feature if it could be bypassed?

Comment: My mac goes to a grey screen with a lock icon on that. I'm thinking that is the firmware lock indication. Am I right on that?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/HT204156 & see if it matches one of those, or add a photo of it to your question.